# Deep-copy of struct with reference member in C++17

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, c++17, move-semantics, deep-copy

I'm still fairly new to C++ and am confused about references and move semantics. For a compiler I'm writing that generates C++17 code, I need to be able to have structs with fields that are other structs. Since the struct definitions will be generated from the user's code in the other language, they could potentially be very large, so I'm storing the inner struct as a reference. This is also necessary to deal with incomplete types that are declared at the beginning but defined later, which may happen in the generated code. (I avoided using pointers because adding `*` all over the place for dereferencing makes the code generation less straightforward.)

The language I'm compiling from has no aliasing, so something like `Outer b = a` should always be a "deep-copy". So in this case, `b.inner` should be a copy of `a.inner` and not a reference to it. But I can't figure out how to setup the constructors to create the deep-copy behavior in C++. I tried many different configurations of the constructors for `Outer`, and I tried both `Inner&` and `Inner&&` for storing `inner`.

Here is a mock example of how the generated code would look:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
T copy(T a) {
    return a;
}

struct Inner;

struct Outer {
    Inner&& inner;
    
    Outer(Inner&& a);
    Outer(Outer& a);
};

struct Inner {
    int v;
};


Outer::Outer(Inner&& a) : inner(std::move(a)) {
    std::cout << " -- Constructor 1 --" << std::endl;
}

// Copy the insides of the original object, then move that rvalue to the new object?
Outer::Outer(Outer& a) : inner(std::move(copy(a.inner))) {
    std::cout << " -- Constructor 2 --" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    Outer a = {Inner {30}};
    std::cout << a.inner.v << std::endl;    // Should be: 30
    a.inner.v += 1;
    std::cout << a.inner.v << std::endl;    // Should be: 31
    
    Outer b = a;   // Copy a to b
    
    std::cout << a.inner.v << std::endl;    // Should be: 31
    std::cout << b.inner.v << std::endl;    // Should be: 31
    
    b.inner.v += 1;
    
    std::cout << a.inner.v << std::endl;    // Should be: 31
    std::cout << b.inner.v << std::endl;    // Should be: 32
    
    return 0;
}
```

And this is what it currently outputs (it may vary by implementation):

```
 -- Constructor 1 --
30
31
 -- Constructor 2 --
297374876
32574
297374876
32574
```

Clearly this output is incorrect, and I think I must have a dangling reference somewhere among other things. How should I setup `Outer` to get the proper behavior here?

Comment: Storing references as members is generally a terrible idea. I would suggest to either accept the size and put the generated struct in as a data member or use heap allocations and smart pointers. As it is, after the semicolon on the line `Outer a = {Inner {30}};` I'm fairly sure that `a.inner` is already dangling.

Comment: Temporaries get destroyed immediately. That means after `Outer a = {Inner {30}};`, `a.inner` is dangling; after `Outer b = a;`, `b.inner` is dangling.

Comment: You didn't say if the source language objects are mutable. If they are, then you don't gain anything by using references or pointers. You need the copies.

Comment: Just have a member of type `Inner` in `Outer`. The games you are playing with references don't make any sense. If you want deep copy, then a) storing by value gives you deep copy for free, and b) one way or another, you would need to allocate an instance of `Inner` for every instance of `Outer`, so references don't save you anything, in fact just add extra overhead.

Comment: @Gene @Igor Tandetnik Yes, objects in the source language can be mutable. The concern wasn't really about avoiding copying for efficiency, it was more about how large data structures would be represented. If you make some large data structure in the source language, and then all the members are inlined in C++, then you could potentially run out of space on the stack. But I think ```unique_ptr``` is probably closer to what I was looking for instead of a raw reference, as the answers pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

> (I avoided using pointers because adding * all over the place for dereferencing makes the code generation less straightforward.)

Don't let your desired interface interfere so much with your implementation. Separation of interface and implementation is a powerful tool.

Your goal is a deep copy. Your temporaries will not live long enough. Something has to own the copied data so it both lives long enough (no dangling references) and does not live too long (no leaked memory). A reference does not own its data. Since the data will not be directly part of your structure, you need a pointer with ownership semantics.

This does not mean that the code has to add de-referencing "all over the place". To aid your interface, you could have a reference to the object owned by the pointer. Normally this would be wasted space, but it might serve a purpose in your project, assuming your assessment about code generation is accurate.

Example:

```cpp
struct Outer {
    // Order matters here! The pointer must be declared before the reference!
    // (This should be less of a problem for generated code than it can be for
    // code edited by human programmers.)
    const std::unique_ptr<Inner> inner_ptr;
    Inner & inner;
    // The idea is that `inner` refers to `*inner_ptr`, and the `const` on
    // `inner_ptr` will prevent `inner` from becoming a dangling reference.

    // Copy constructor
    Outer(const Outer& src) :
        inner_ptr(std::make_unique<Inner>(src.inner)),  // Make a copy
        inner(*inner_ptr)                               // Reference to the copy
    {}

    // The compiler-generated assignment operator will be deleted because
    // of the reference member, just as in the question's code
    // (so having it deleted because of the `unique_ptr` is not an issue).
    // However, to make this explicit:
    Outer& operator=(const Outer&) = delete;
};
```

With the above setup, you could still access the members of the inner data via syntax like `object.inner.field`. While this is redundant with access via the `object.inner_ptr->field` syntax, you indicated that you have established a need for the former syntax.

**For the benefit of future readers:**
*This approach has drawbacks that would normally cause me to recommend against it. It is a judgement call as to which drawbacks are greater – those in this approach or the "less straightforward" code generation. Sometimes machine-generated code needs a bit of inefficiency to ensure that corner cases function correctly. So this might be acceptable in this particular case.*

---

If I may stray a bit from your desired syntax, a neater option would be to have an accessor function. Whether or not this is applicable in your situation depends on details that are appropriately out-of-scope for this question. It might be worth considering.

Instead of wasting space by storing a reference in the structure, you could generate the reference as needed via a member function. This has the side-effect of removing the need to mark the pointer `const`.

```cpp
struct Outer {
    // Note the lack of restrictions imposed on the data.
    // All that might be needed is an assertion that inner_ptr will never be null.
    std::unique_ptr<Inner> inner_ptr;

    // Here, `inner` will be a member function instead of member data.
    Inner & inner() { return *inner_ptr; }
    // And a const version for good measure.
    const Inner & inner() const { return *inner_ptr; }

    // Copy constructor
    Outer(const Outer& src) :
        inner_ptr(std::make_unique<Inner>(src.inner()))  // Make a copy
    {}

    // With this setup, the compiler-generated copy assignment
    // operator is still deleted because of the `unique_ptr`.
    // However, a compiler-generated *move* assignment is
    // available if you specifically request it.
    Outer& operator=(const Outer&) = delete;
    Outer& operator=(Outer &&) = default;
};
```

With this setup, access to the members of the inner data could be done via syntax like `object.inner().field`. I don't know if the extra parentheses will cause the same issues as the asterisks would.

Comment: About the drawbacks of the first approach: consider what happens upon assignment.

Comment: @eerorika Isn't assignment implicitly deleted because of the reference member? (I thought that was the case, which is why I skipped mentioning assignment in the first approach.) If I am wrong about that, I'll explicitly delete assignment.

Comment: why would a reference member delete assignment?  Your plan makes the type non-regular, which is almost always a bad plan.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont According to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment#Deleted_implicitly-declared_copy_assignment_operator), "A defaulted copy assignment operator for class T is defined as *deleted* if [... or] T has a non-static data member of a reference type [or ...]."

Comment: @jamit huh.  Would you believe I have need manually deleting them consistently for about a decade and never seen that implicit delete error message?  I swore there was a thing where it could run if not deleted.

Answer (score 2):

References in C++ are (almost always) non owning aliases.

You do not want a non owning alias.

Thus, do not use references.

You could have an owning (smart) pointer and a reference alias to make some code generation easier.  Do not do this.  The result of doing it is a class with mixed semantics; there is no coherant sensible `operator=` and copy/move constructors you can write in that case.

My advice would be to:

1. Write a `value_ptr` that inherits from `unique_ptr` but copies on assignment.

then either:

2. Generate code with `->`

or

3. Add a helper method that returns `*ptr` reference, and generate code that does `method()`.

Comment: Thanks, this is probably the closest to what I was looking for. I found this implementation of ```value_ptr``` ([link](https://github.com/Enhex/value_ptr)) that also overloads variable access so dereferencing with ```*``` isn't necessary. However, apparently it isn't possible to overload ```.``` in C++, so there's no way to make ```a.inner.v``` work without a reference alias. So I'll probably write my own ```value_ptr```, and I guess I'll have to suck it up and generate code with ```->```.

Comment: @Jamie Yes, generating code with `->` is a good plan.  `operator.` overloading has been proposed, but never made it in the standard yet.  I would, however, still recommend doing `*` when you want to copy it to a scalar; this is generated code, you'll know it is a pointer.  Implicit conversion can lead to nasty surprises...

Answer (score 0):

Deep copying only makes sense when the class has ownership. A reference isn't generally used for owernship.

> Clearly this output is incorrect, and I think I must have a dangling reference somewhere among other things

You've guessed correctly. In the declaration: `Outer a = {Inner {30}};` The instance of `Inner` is a temporary object and its lifetime extends until the end of that declaration. After that, the reference member is left dangling.

> so I'm storing the inner struct as a reference

A reference doesn't store an object. A reference refers to an object that is stored somewhere else.

> How should I setup Outer to get the proper behavior here?

It seems that a smart pointer might be useful for your use case:

```
struct Outer {
    std::unique_ptr<Inner> inner;
};
```

You'll need to define a deep copy constructor and assignment operator though.

Comment: There are some quirky reference lifetime extension stuff that could make a statement about dangling references above wrong, but I do not know the state of it in [tag:c++20], and it is so fragile that the OP should not rely on it anyhow.  (the OP would have to remove the user provided ctor)